# How to get & set Chart In "View Code"?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

Im working with C# winforms.

Hi, I need to know how to get & set Chart In "View Code" ? I mean to syntax.

For example to set ComboBox Im doing:

```
public ComboBox CmbEmployeeName
{
     get { return _cmbEmployeeName; }
     set { _cmbEmployeeName = value; }
}
```

Thanks All!

Comment: I mean the view code of the Add >> "Windows Form"

Comment: Do you need a type of chart? It's [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your data directly with data source property.

```
chrtCompany.DataSource = data;//this is your data
chrtCompany.DataBind();
```

Obviously you need set chart XValueMember and YValueMembers from chart properties first.

Comment: I want to show in the chart sum of orders quantity for each month.
i know oh to write the query but i always set each tool in the "view code" of the form as I said in the top of the page. so i dont know how to set Chart/Graph